# SQL Case Value Switching

Tags: sql, select, case

I am passing a series of double values in from another table ranging from -1 to 1. If the value is positive, I want to make it the difference between it and 1 (ie. 0.2 would then become .8).  If value is negative, I want it to be the delta negative now above 1 (ie. 0.2 would be 1.2).

For some reason when I do this, it is taking the values from the previous table and making them fit the condition of the first WHEN (so in this setup, all the passed in values are being made positive and hitting the first WHEN).

Why isn't this working?

```
SELECT SnapshotDay
    ,SnapshotHour
    ,CASE
        WHEN Delta > 0.0 THEN (1 - Delta)
        WHEN Delta <= 0.0 THEN (abs(Delta) + 1)
        END as Adjust
FROM #Difference
```

Example:

```
-0.00118341262814151 -->  0.998816587371859
 0.00130811285278974 -->  0.99869188714721
```

Comment: Whats the data type of `delta`?

Comment: Is your example the desired result, or the incorrect result?

Comment: Double; and it was the incorrect - D Stanley's observation let me avoid it entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're seeing the results you are, but mathematically your expected result is just `1 - Delta`:

```
SELECT SnapshotDay
    ,SnapshotHour
    ,(1 - Delta) as Adjust
FROM #Difference
```

If `Delta` is positive it will be substracted from 1:

```
(1 - Delta)
```

If `Delta` is negative the absolute value will be added to 1:

```
(-1*Delta + 1) == (1 - Delta)
```

Comment: Haven't figured out why my setup didn't work; however you're totally right.  That change let me skip the CASE altogether, and now it works properly.  Thank you!